# Check if atleast one field is not empty in PHP

Tags: php

I have these fields: `weight, size_1, size_2, size_3`

How can I check so minimum one of these fields are filled.

If its under the minimum then it should output "Error, fill one atleast"

I can do this with long if statements, that checks for empty, but is their a better way?

The fields come from an form submission, so it looks like this to get them:

```
$_POST['weight'];
$_POST['size_1'];
$_POST['size_2'];
$_POST['size_3'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming they are all in an array:

```
function check_for_input($array){
     foreach($array as $value){
           if($value != "") return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Use it like so:

```
if(check_for_input($_POST)){ /*...*/ }
else { die("Error, fill one at least"); }
```

---

#### Update with filter:

Assuming they are all in an array:

```
function check_for_input($array, $filter){
     foreach($array as $key=>$value){
           if($value != "" && in_array($key, $filter)){ 
                return true;
           }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Use it like so:

```
$filter = array('weight', 'size_1', 'size_2', 'size_3', /*...*/);
if(check_for_input($_POST, $filter)){ /*...*/ }
else { die("Error, fill one at least"); }
```

Comment: And i can see you did $_POST.. I have other fields/variables in $_POST, and they are always filled with some values, so it will not work properly as it will make that if statement true always ( since they always are filled )

Comment: that `null` looks horrible , it should be `!== ""`. also what happens if a script kiddie sends size_4=bla but all the fields are empty?

Comment: @yi_H -- the OP only wanted at least  **one**  to be filled

Comment: yeah that's what I was saying... your filter approach at least prevents that.

Comment: *sigh* I did, what made you think I didn't? have you fixed `null`? you shouldn't advertise bad practice, with that many reputation points people trust you.

Comment: @yi_H `null` was fixed. I used `!=` and **not** `!==`