# Check for atleast one filled field in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Check if atleast one field is not empty in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407865/check-if-atleast-one-field-is-not-empty-in-php)

is very equal to this question. This is just how to do it in javascript.

When you click on #submit it should check atleast one of these fields:

```
input[name=weight], input[name=size_1], input[name=size_2], input[name=size_3]
```

are filled, and not empty. If all of them are empty, it should alert("Please fill one of the fields")

**Update: forgot to mention that if the fields are 0 it should not be counted as filled.**

How can i do this? I tried copy over from php, but i get stuck on the foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this very easily with the `filter` method:

```
var filledFields = $('input[name=weight], input[name=size_1], input[name=size_2], input[name=size_3]')
    .filter(function() {
        return !!this.value && this.value !== '0'; // remove if value is empty or 0, keep otherwise
    });

if (filledFields.length) {
    // at least one element has a value set
} else {
    // no fields have values set
    alert("Please fill one of the fields")
}
```

What this does:

1. Selects all the elements you want to check
2. Runs the `filter` method: if you return true, the element will be kept; if you return false, it will be removed from the selection

   - `!!this.value` is `true` if the value is a non-empty string and otherwise is false
3. We then check the `length` property of the selection. If it is not `0`, at least one element has a non-empty value. If it is `0`, they are all empty.

See:

- [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)
- [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length)

Comment: I forgot to mention if its 0 it should not be counted as filled

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$("input[name=weight]").val() && !$("input[name=size_1]").val() && !$("input[name=size_2]").val() && !$("input[name=size_3]").val()){
    alert('Please fill one of the fields');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {
    var fields = $(this).find('input[name=weight]', 'input[name=size_1]', 'input[name=size_2]', 'input[name=size_3]');
    if (!$fields.filter(function() { return !!$(this).val(); }).length) {
        alert('Please fill one of the fields');
        return false;
    }
});
```